# How to order processes in a nested loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, solana, solana-web3js

So here I'm building a script which will take a token from the list and send it to the wallet from another list. It's very important for me to do it in order, so wallet 1 receives token 1, wallet 2 receives token 2 and so on. I'm doing a nested loop, because I need to get info from both TXT files at the same time.

So here's the code:

```
const shell = require("shelljs");
const fs = require("fs");

const numberToAirdrop = 1;
const pathToTheWLFile = "./wl.txt" // list of wallets
const pathToTheTKFile = "./tk.txt" // list of tokens


const wlFile = fs.readFileSync(pathToTheWLFile).toString().replace(/\r/g, '').split("\n");
const tkFile = fs.readFileSync(pathToTheTKFile).toString().replace(/\r/g, '').split("\n");


console.log(wlFile)
console.log(tkFile)

// Here's where I struggle:

for (const [index, address] of wlFile.entries()) for (const [index2, address2] of tkFile.entries()) {

    if (address.includes("(sent) ") && address2.includes("(sent) ")) {
        console.log(`[${index}][${index2}] Skipping ${address} and ${address2} as has been processed before`);
        continue;
    }

    console.log(`[${index}] [${index2}] Airdropping ${numberToAirdrop} of ${address2} to ${address}`);
    console.time("Sent in")

    const output = shell.exec(`spl-token transfer ${address2} ${numberToAirdrop} ${address} --allow-unfunded-recipient --fund-recipient -v`); // transfer process

    if (output.stderr && output.code !== 0) {
        throw new Error(
            `[${index}] ${index2}] Failed to send ${address2} to the ${address} ` +
            `last '${"(sent) to" + wlFile[index] && tkFile[index2]}'`
        )
    }

    tkFile[index2] = "(sent) " + tkFile[index2]
    wlFile[index] = "(sent) " + wlFile[index]
    fs.writeFileSync(pathToTheWLFile, wlFile.join("\n"));
    fs.writeFileSync(pathToTheTKFile, tkFile.join("\n"));

    console.log(`[${index}][${index2}] Airdropping ${numberToAirdrop} of ${address2} to ${address} has been successful\n\n`);
    console.timeEnd("Sent in")
}


const notDone = wlFile.find((i) => !i.includes("(sent)"));
if (notDone) {
    console.log("Upload did not finish for all the addresses please re run")
    return;
}

console.log("Upload is done! All the tokens have been airdropped!")
```

Basically it works, but in a nested loop way, I mean it sends token 1 to wallet 1, but then tries to send the same token to wallet 2, then it sends token 2 to wallet 1. And I need it to work in order, so wallet 1 receives token 1, wallet 2 receives token 2 and so on, without repeatable actions. Is it possible in a nested loop?

Comment: Do you try to order an object?

Comment: I've rewritten the task, hopefully now it will be more obvious what I'm trying to do. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a nested for-loop. What you need is a single for-loop instead

```
for (let i = 0; i < list1.length && i < list2.length; i++) {
    let number1 = list1[i];
    let number2 = list2[i];
    //do your stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but not sure if it will work for my task.. I've rewritten the question completely, please review it when you can.